# Creating new kind in Google datastore using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created a web application with google app engine.

I have a kind named userbean. It has details related to user such as name, age and email.

I have creater a bean class for it.

I have added and deleted entities to it.

But when I create a new kind called **wordbean** and tried to store data of this type to datastore, it doesn't save them in datastore. How to create a new kind and store it in google datastore?

Is there any rule that only one kind can exist in a datastore?
     //controller class
     //function which requests parameters from user through html, jquery

```
 DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
     Transaction txn=datastore.beginTransaction();

     Entity Word = new Entity("WordBean");

     Word.setProperty("word", "அறிவியல்");
     Word.setProperty("length", "5");


     Word.setProperty("start", "அ");

     Word.setProperty("starttwo", "அறி");
     Word.setProperty("Detail", "பாடங்களில் ஒன்று.");

     datastore.put(Word); 
     txn.commit();
 //end
```

Comment: Is this the same code you used for the userbean entity that worked? if not, what's different? also, have you checked the logs for errors? How did you check if the entity was created?

Comment: It doesn't show any message in console. :( I also viewed datastore in localhost (http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin). I checked all options. But i could not find my new kind.

Comment: are you sure that you looked for the new kind in the select box in http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore

Comment: @MosheShaham Yes. I checked it many times. Refershed that page many times. Checked console. Nothing Worked. Can you give me an example so that I can try yours. Please give an example bean class and the function in controller to add it in data store. I am using spring along with Google app engine.

Comment: Please: 

1) add the full code sample that shows in which context this code is being executed. 2) add logging messages so that you can be sure that your code is being executed. 3) use lowercase letters to begin variable names (ie. "word" instead of "Word")